# How to save video files using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

I am learning MySQL through the MySQL shell (using MySQL Workbench 8.0 on Windows 10) and I have already used tables to save text and digits. Now I want to store multimedia files (e.g. videos) in a MySQL database.

I know about the blob format but don't know how to use it.

This is some SQL that I have written:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS arit
  (
     id       INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
     type     CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     price    DECIMAL(6, 2) NOT NULL,
     quantity INT DEFAULT 0
  );

INSERT INTO arit
            (type,
             price,
             quantity)
VALUES     ("red",
            10.22,
            12);

INSERT INTO arit
            (type,
             price,
             quantity)
VALUES     ("blue",
            19.22,
            33);

INSERT INTO arit
            (type,
             price,
             quantity)
VALUES     ("rose",
            29.20,
            24);

SELECT *
FROM   arit;

SELECT type,
       price                                                     AS bottle,
       quantity                                                  AS qty,
       price * quantity                                          AS subtotal,
       ( price * quantity ) * ( 6 / 100 )                        AS tax,
       ( price * quantity ) + ( price * quantity ) * ( 6 / 100 ) AS total,
       ( price + quantity ) * 100                                AS something
FROM   arit;
```

Comment: How do you use MySQL? Do you use it via PHP or do you work directly with a database manager? Knowing about your setup could help answering your question in more detail :)

Comment: I am using mysql directly with workBench .

Comment: Oh this is very important information; in that case, can you please provide the version of `MySQL Workbench` and our operating system? Also consider tagging `MySQL Workbench` in your question as there might be people out there who know that program well (I don't). Getting videos into your database via `MySQL Workbench` will depend greatly on the software stack you're using.

Comment: i have installed Worbench 8.0 ce on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

If you know about the `BLOB` format already, storing video files is not different to storing any other arbitrary binary data in a database.  Depending on your underlying language, you have to read the video file in binary mode first (e.g. [`fread`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) in PHP) and then write the binary stream into a `BLOB` field into database.

**UPDATE**: this answer isn't relevant anymore after discovering that the question is rather about MySQL Workbench than about MySQL in general.  This answer could still provide some insight however, which is why I haven't deleted it (yet).

Comment: As discussed, the real issue here is obtaining the video data in binary format and _not_ storing binary data into a database. The former depends heavily on your software stack, the latter is as simple as `INSERT INTO table_name(video_col) VALUES(video_data)` where `video_data` is the data itself.